# Could not resolve placeholder 'database.driverClassName' in string value

Tags: database, tomcat, jdbc, dependencies

When the server starts working (Tomcat), the log show this error:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Invalid bean definition with name 'dataSource' defined in file [D:\workspace-sts-3.5.0.RELEASE\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps\App\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'database.driverClassName' in string value "${database.driverClassName}"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`${database.driverClassName}` is a placeholder for a driver classname. You have to specify it in a config file or as a parameter at start of the application.

Comment: the database.properties was not being found. Placed and executed. Thanks